# GTM-E-RPARENMISSING error when signing meds in CPRS / VistA

Tags: mumps

I have an instance of OSEHRA VistA set up using the [Vagrant autoinstaller](https://github.com/OSEHRA/VistA/blob/master/Documentation/Install/Vagrant.rst), and using an imported KIDS drug file following [these instructions](http://www.vistapedia.com/index.php/KIDS_Drug_File).  Users with correct permissions are able to enter and save med orders in CPRS using entries from the drug file, but when they try to sign the orders, CPRS throws this error:

```
M ERROR=ES1+12^ORCACT01, Right Parenthesis Expected, 150373642,-%GTM-E-RPARENMISSING LAST REF=^PSDRUG(“ASP”,6,1254)
```

As yet, this installation has no customized code. What might be causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow. A question in a subject I am an expert in.

I know this error well. It's caused by a developer using || or &&. These work on Cache; but not on GT.M, as they are not standard MUMPS. If you change the || to ! and the && to &, it will work in GT.M using the exact same semantics. I won't add more here as this is will get into the weeds.

The bug has been reported and will be fixed in future releases from the VA.

FYI, I am the author of the KIDS drug file. I am glad you find it useful.

Comment: Oh BTW, if you asked on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/Hardhats, you would have gotten an answer very quickly. We VISTA folks "hang out" over there.